# Wow animation: what if JS fails?

Tags: javascript, wow.js

I'm using [Wow.JS](https://wowjs.uk/) to animate website elements. To prevent elements from first showing, then disappearing and then appearing again (animation) when using wow, I added the CSS line:

```
.wow { visibility:none;}
```

However, this causes elements to stay hidden when JS fails or disabled in browser. For that, I created this little  / script function:

```
<!-- wow backup -->
<noscript><style>.wow {visibility: initial;}</style></noscript>
<script>window.onload=function(){elem = document.querySelector('.wow');style = getComputedStyle(elem);if (style.visibility=='hidden') {style = document.createElement('style');document.head.appendChild(style);style.sheet.insertRule('.wow { visibility:initial;}');}}</script>
```

I know this place is for asking questions but I just wanted to share this little snipped for everyone using wow. How do you solve these wow issues (flickering before animating / js fails)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a message board. Feel free to self-answer, but segment your original post into an actual, concrete question and an answer, the latter of which should be posted separately down below. Right now, it's difficult to tell if the script you've provided is working and if you're asking for support with it, or if you've simply provided both a question and the answer in the body of your original question post.